# How to configure SourceConnector in confluent cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i'am new to confluent cloud,i want to configure SourceConnector for Azur SQL,i am not able to understand how to and where to configure SourceConnector in confluent cloud.

Comment: Read this? https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/connect/connect-cloud-config.html

Comment: All Right sir,But I'm not getting the SourceConnector configurations..

Comment: I'm not sure which source connector you're looking for. JDBC? Do you know how to configure any other source connector? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: I am looking for Azur SQL Source Connector,Yes i know source connector configuration. i did that poc on confluent 5.2.1 on aws but now i want to do that on confluent cloud, when i click on connector->add connector then i am getting only sink connector option, one more thing is inside documentation there is no  source connector configuration guide.

Comment: Only S3 and GCP sinks are supported in Confluent Cloud. You need to run your own Connect instances in AWS with EC2 or EKS, as the documentation shows by setup of a generic worker. By default, JDBC is the only source provided by Confluent Platform. You must install the Azur plugin yourself

Comment: Ok, Thanks Sir...

Answer (score 0):

As of this post, only S3 and GCS (preview) **sinks** are offered as [Connectors on Confluent Cloud](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/connectors/index.html)

To get sources, you would need to [manage your own deployment of Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/connect/connect-cloud-config.html), whether that is in EC2, ECS, or EKS